# PowerShell - lowercase first word after special character in txt files

Tags: regex, powershell, text, special-characters, lowercase

I have a lot of .txt files where I need to lowercase every instance of a string/word after the character "%" but not the following words after the first word. I'm trying to do it in PowerShell.

I have this:

```
%WORD WORD2 WORD3 %WORD4
```

I need this:

```
%word WORD2 WORD3 %word4
```

The code below makes all content in the files lowercase and I need it to only do it in all instances of the first word after the character "%".

```
$path=".\*.txt"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | foreach{    
    (Get-Content $_.FullName).ToLower() | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Ando, I forgot the answer your question in the comment. 
This is how the regex should look like: 
`(?s)(?<=%)(\w+).*(?=;)`

[image]

Here the code to lowercase the first word:

```
$path=".\*.txt"
$callback = {  param($match) $match.Groups[1].Value.ToLower() }
$rex = [regex]'(?s)(?<=%)(\w+).*(?=;)'

Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $rex.Replace((Get-Content $_ -raw), $callback) | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```

---

**Note:**
If you don't need to do that for every word **between** `%` an `;`, then the regex would be:

```
(?<=%)(\w+)
```

Comment: The last regex was excactly what I needed. You've been very helpful. Thank You very much.